# Absolute positioning an element on the circumference of a circle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on to place an icon to the bottom right of an image having the property of border-radius: 50%. 
Here's what I want to achieve(Icon to be on the circumference),

[image]

By absolute and relative positioning, I can place the icon as expected but on smaller screens, the icon goes out of place due to image resizing (with img-fluid class of bootstrap 4).

[image]

How can I make the icon to be at the same place across all screens even after image resizes?

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

.image{
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #008080;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 22px;
  bottom: 42px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x350' class='image img-fluid'/>
  <span class='icon'></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `right` and `bottom` as % not px
Do the same for height and width if you want size to adapt. See my snippet

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

.image{
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon{
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  background: #008080;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x350' class='image img-fluid'/>
  <span class='icon'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I did try setting the `bottom` and `right` properties in % but it didn't work. The icon was still out of place but this time with a **smaller margin**.

Comment: @ChetanKalra do the same for height and width. run my snippet and resize - it work perfect

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the desired result you need to position the center of the small circle (with a dimension of `0px` × `0px`) at the desired height/width of the bigger one and draw the small circle around this center.

Do note that if you want your positioning done responsively you need to do it in percentage, not in `px`.

Since functionality required from the child is purely visual, you can safely use a pseudo element:

```
.icon {
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   position: absolute;
}
.icon:after {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

In terms of centering, you have a couple of options:

a) `transform:translate(-50%,-50%)`

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

.image {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16%;
  bottom: 13.5%;
  overflow: visible;
}

.icon:before {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #008080;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='wrapper'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x350' class='image img-fluid' />
  <span class='icon'></span>
</div>
```

b) flexbox on parent:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

.image {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon {
  height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16%;
    bottom: 13.5%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: visible;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.icon:before {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #008080;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='wrapper'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x350' class='image img-fluid' />
  <span class='icon'></span>
</div>
```

To rotate the small circle on the bigger one you can do it mathematically or you could do as I did: I made the `:after` `3px` × `3px`, changed `%` of any combo of `top|bottom` + `left|right` to the desired location on the bigger center circumference and increase the size of the small center back to `50px` * `50px`.

Also, to size the smaller circle down responsively, you could express the width and height in `vw` under a particular viewport width, making sure at the point where it starts shrinking the size in `px` with the one in `vw` translate to the same actual size. Example:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

.image {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon {
  height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16%;
    bottom: 13.5%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: visible;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.icon:before {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #008080;
  display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 350px) {
  .icon:before {
    width: calc(10vw - 6px);
    height: calc(10vw - 6px);
    min-width: 5px;
    min-height: 5px;
    /* 60px making up for the padding on .wrapper */
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='wrapper'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x350' class='image img-fluid' />
  <span class='icon'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Another great solution! Thanks.